# Moving functionalty with background tasks from main activity into it's own separate class

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth, encapsulation, kotlin-coroutines

In my kotlin app I want to move all the bluetooth related functionality into it's own class.
While it is clear to me how to move a method into a separate class, I do not clearly see how to move a method into a class that updates data in the background.

How do I trigger the main activity after the bluetooth class receives some data in the background (currently a coroutine running a read loop)
Here is for example the function that reads incoming bluetooth data. It works fine but updates the UI directly:

```
private suspend fun readBT() {
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var receivedSoFar = ""

    /* Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs or cancel is set. */
    while (state == "connected") {
        try {
            /* nrOfBytes will hold the number of bytes in the buffer */
            val nrOfBytes = inStream?.read(buffer)
            /*  add buffer content to current line */
            receivedSoFar += String(buffer, 0, nrOfBytes!!)
            /* until (incl) newline character */
            if (receivedSoFar.contains("\n")) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { txt_state.text = (receivedSoFar.dropLast(1)) }
                receivedSoFar = ""
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            if (state == "connected") {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { txt_state.text = "error while reading bt data from Wallie" }
                state = "error_during_read"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really provide some code at a minimum if you want an answer from someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MainActivity` and the new `BluetoothClass` should communicate through a callback. The callback can be a parameter of `BluetoothClass`' constructor:

```
class BluetoothClass(
  private val updateText: (String) -> Unit,
  ...
)
```

and `MainActivity` will pass in an implementation of that lambda when instantiating `BluetoothClass`:

```
bluetoothClass = BluetoothClass(updateText = { text -> txt_state.text = text })
```

Lastly, `BluetoothClass` should invoke the lambda whenever it needs to update the text:

```
if (receivedSoFar.contains("\n")) {
  withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { updateText(receivedSoFar.dropLast(1)) }
  receivedSoFar = ""
}
```

Comment: Thank you Egor, I will set this up like you suggest and report result.

Comment: … and it works beautifully. Main activity looks much cleaner now with all that bluetooth code neatly in it's own class.

Comment: Glad it helped!